# Spring Tags and JQuery validator

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a form that I wish to validate with JQuery validator plugin. 
After following the example using a plain jsp, I get this error once I add Spring tags. 
Here is my JSP:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Employees</title>

</head>
<body>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <h3>Persons List</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="employee">
                <tr>
                    <td>${employee.userName}</td>
                    <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${employee.phoneNumber}</td>
                    <td>${employee.role}</td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${employee}' />">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${employee}' />">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!--                           addition form                                  -->
    <div class="container" id="additionDiv">
        <h2>Create Employee</h2>

        <%-- <sf:form method="post" class="form-horizontal"
            action="persistEmployee" modelAttribute="employee"> --%>

        <sf:form method="post" class="form-horizontal"
            modelAttribute="employee" id="additionForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                <sf:label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="uname"
                    path="userName">User Name:</sf:label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <sf:input class="form-control" id="uname" path="userName" name="uname" minlength="4" type="text" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <sf:label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fname"
                    path="firstName">First Name:</sf:label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <sf:input class="form-control" id="fname" path="firstName" name="fname"  type="text" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <sf:label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname" path="lastName">Last Name:</sf:label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <sf:input class="form-control" id="lname" path="lastName" name="lname" type="text" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <sf:label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pnumber"
                    path="phoneNumber">Phone Number</sf:label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <sf:input class="form-control" id="pnumber" path="phoneNumber" name="pnumber" minlength="7" type="digit" required  />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <sf:label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="role" path="role">Role</sf:label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <sf:select path="role" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"
                        id="sel1">
                        <sf:option value="CONSULTANT"></sf:option>
                        <sf:option value="MANAGER"></sf:option>
                        <sf:option value="ADMIN"></sf:option>
                    </sf:select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </sf:form>
    </div>
    <!--                           end addition form                                  -->

    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-button">+</button>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add-button").click(function() {
            $("#additionDiv").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addition-form").validate();
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addition-form").submit(function() {
            alert("form submitted");
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Here is the exception I'm getting, I don't know where the equal sign should be.

```
Sep 15, 2016 4:38:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/employees.jsp (line: 69, column: 111) equal symbol expected
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:218)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:163)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:154)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1455)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1668)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:996)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1271)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1455)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does your source code run without jQuery validator plugin?

Comment: If you mean while using 'required', No it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I think, it could be because of the attributes minlength, type and required. They are not in the TLD.

```
<sf:input class="form-control" id="uname" path="userName" name="uname" minlength="4" type="text" required />
```

You can see the TLD doc here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html

Comment: You are correct. So is there a way around this? or do I have to abandon my attempt to use the JQuery plugin. I'm new to both JSP's and JQuery (web development in general)

Answer (score 0):

Spring expects each attribute to have a value. Since `required` is a boolean attribute, only its presence is necessary, so you can give it any value. By convention, this value is usually the name of the attribute itself.

```
<sf:input class="form-control" id="uname" 
    path="userName" name="uname" minlength="4" type="text" 
    required="required"/>
```